# LoadError when rct-complete-symbol is called by rcodetools in Emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

I installed rcodetools in Emacs by `gem install rcodetools` and copy `rcodetools.el` to directory that is inside of Emacs loadpath.

And write initial file of emacs like this.

```
(require 'rcodetools)
(defun ruby-mode-hook-rcodetools ()
  (define-key ruby-mode-map (kbd "<C-tab>") 'rct-complete-symbol)
  (define-key ruby-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'xmp))
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ruby-mode-hook-rcodetools)
```

When I call `rct-complete-symbol` I get following error.

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- rct-complete (LoadError)
```

I could not even know which file and which line this error occurs.

How can I solve this problem?

*Problem solved*

It was because of my silly mistake. I'm using `rbenv` and I totally forgot about the `rbenv rehash`.

Comment: Last time I tried to set up `rcodetools`, it failed in some similar way. If you want completion, try [robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe).

Comment: The problem have occurred because I forgot doing `rbenv rehash`. Thanks anyway!